# gemini api request fails due to permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-gemini

I've requested gemini api answering question from videos.

but it fails messaging 403 error. I've logged in with my personal email and json has the service email infos of project. I couldn't find similar questions from me.
is it data bucket or vertex ai?

```
!pip3 install --upgrade --user google-cloud-aiplatform

import vertexai
# from google.cloud import aiplatform

PROJECT_ID = "[my-project-id]"  # @param {type:"string"}
LOCATION = "asia-northeast2"  # @param {type:"string"}


vertexai.init(project=PROJECT_ID, location=LOCATION)
from vertexai.preview.generative_models import GenerativeModel, Part
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_FILE = 'my-json-path' # full path
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_FILE # 
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
  SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_FILE, scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"])

credentials.refresh(Request())
access_token = credentials.token
gemini_model = GenerativeModel("gemini-pro-vision")
video_uri = f"gs://video/highlight_001.mp4"
video = Part.from_uri(video_uri, mime_type="video/mp4")
response = gemini_model.generate_content(
        [
            video,
            """Answer the following questions below with yes or no.
            - Is there a person laughing loudly in the video? 
            """
        ]
    )
print(response)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
_MultiThreadedRendezvous                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py:173, in _wrap_stream_errors.<locals>.error_remapped_callable(*args, **kwargs)
    172     prefetch_first = getattr(callable_, "_prefetch_first_result_", True)
--> 173     return _StreamingResponseIterator(
    174         result, prefetch_first_result=prefetch_first
    175     )
    176 except grpc.RpcError as exc:

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py:95, in _StreamingResponseIterator.__init__(self, wrapped, prefetch_first_result)
     94     if prefetch_first_result:
---> 95         self._stored_first_result = next(self._wrapped)
     96 except TypeError:
     97     # It is possible the wrapped method isn't an iterable (a grpc.Call
     98     # for instance). If this happens don't store the first result.

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py:540, in _Rendezvous.__next__(self)
    539 def __next__(self):
--> 540     return self._next()

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py:966, in _MultiThreadedRendezvous._next(self)
    965 elif self._state.code is not None:
--> 966     raise self

_MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED
    details = "Permission denied on resource project [my-project-id]."
    debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv4:172.217.24.74:443 {created_time:"2024-01-23T12:13:22.000599+09:00", grpc_status:7, grpc_message:"Permission denied on resource project [my-project-id]."}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

PermissionDenied                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[28], line 3
      1 video_uri = f"gs://broadcast_video_data/highlight_001.mp4"
      2 video = Part.from_uri(video_uri, mime_type="video/mp4")
----> 3 response = gemini_model.generate_content(
      4         [
      5             video,
      6             """Answer the following questions below with yes or no.
      7             - Is there a person laughing loudly in the video?
     11             """
     12         ]
     13     )
     14 print(response)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/vertexai/generative_models/_generative_models.py:353, in _GenerativeModel.generate_content(self, contents, generation_config, safety_settings, tools, stream)
    346     return self._generate_content_streaming(
    347         contents=contents,
    348         generation_config=generation_config,
    349         safety_settings=safety_settings,
    350         tools=tools,
    351     )
    352 else:
--> 353     return self._generate_content(
    354         contents=contents,
    355         generation_config=generation_config,
    356         safety_settings=safety_settings,
    357         tools=tools,
    358     )

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/vertexai/generative_models/_generative_models.py:437, in _GenerativeModel._generate_content(self, contents, generation_config, safety_settings, tools)
    434 # generate_content is not available
    435 # gapic_response = self._prediction_client.generate_content(request=request)
    436 gapic_response = None
--> 437 stream = self._prediction_client.stream_generate_content(request=request)
    438 for gapic_chunk in stream:
    439     if gapic_response:

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform_v1beta1/services/prediction_service/client.py:1634, in PredictionServiceClient.stream_generate_content(self, request, model, contents, retry, timeout, metadata)
   1629 metadata = tuple(metadata) + (
   1630     gapic_v1.routing_header.to_grpc_metadata((("model", request.model),)),
   1631 )
   1633 # Send the request.
-> 1634 response = rpc(
   1635     request,
   1636     retry=retry,
   1637     timeout=timeout,
   1638     metadata=metadata,
   1639 )
   1641 # Done; return the response.
   1642 return response

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py:131, in _GapicCallable.__call__(self, timeout, retry, compression, *args, **kwargs)
    128 if self._compression is not None:
    129     kwargs["compression"] = compression
--> 131 return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py:177, in _wrap_stream_errors.<locals>.error_remapped_callable(*args, **kwargs)
    173     return _StreamingResponseIterator(
    174         result, prefetch_first_result=prefetch_first
    175     )
    176 except grpc.RpcError as exc:
--> 177     raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc

PermissionDenied: 403 Permission denied on resource project [my-project-id]. [links {
  description: "Google developers console"
  url: "https://console.developers.google.com"
}
, reason: "CONSUMER_INVALID"
domain: "googleapis.com"
metadata {
  key: "service"
  value: "aiplatform.googleapis.com"
}
metadata {
  key: "consumer"
  value: "projects/[my-project-id]"
}
]
```

gcloud login, authentication
vertex ai region changing,

Comment: Did you enable the service `aiplatform.googleapis.com`? Where are you running this code? What IAM roles are assigned to the principal (service account)? Edit your post with more details.